# SQL Server 2008 automated nightly database backup

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-backups

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Web Edition and I'd like to create an automated nightly backup that saves the .bak file to a local directory like C:\DB-backups with the following naming structure dbname-date.bak (dbname-07032012.bak).

I'm not picky about the date format, as long as it's readable and unique.

I'd like to schedule the backup be automated and to run at 3am EST every single night for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not that easy as it is with the standard(oh higher) versions of sql server. There you can set maintenance plans to do the job.

In your case, create a stored procedure to use ie. `EXEC BackupDatabases`. This link shows you how to do it:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2019698/how-to-schedule-and-automate-backups-of-sql-server-databases-in-sql-se